# resolveComponent can only be used in render() or setup()

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, laravel-nova

I'm using laravel nova 4 for creating an admin panel. I'm trying to override a existed nova component. This is what I have done:

- Create `BelongsToField.vue` in `resources/js/nova/components/Form`, then copy all context in `vendor/laravel/nova/resources/js/components/Form/BelongsTo.vue`
- Add `fields.js` file in `resources/js/nova`, this is my file:

```
import BelongsToField from './components/Form/BelongsToField'

Nova.booting((app, store) => {
    app.component('FormBelongsToField', BelongsToField);
})
```

- Then create `webpack.mix.js`:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');

mix.setPublicPath('public')
  .js('resources/js/nova/fields.js', 'js')
  .vue({ version: 3 });
```

- Then, adding script to `NovaServiceProvider`

```
public function boot()
{
  parent::boot();

  Nova::serving(function (ServingNova $event) {
    Nova::script('belongs-to-field', __DIR__ . '/../../public/js/fields.js');
  });
}
```

- Because laravel nova 4 uses `vite` instead of `webpack`, so I migrate back my application to use s `webpack` following [this](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-vite-to-laravel-mix) (I tried with `vite`, but it doesn't work, so I change to `webpack`)
- After install all dependencies, this is my `package.json` file:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production",
        "prepare": "husky install"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@commitlint/cli": "^17.0.3",
        "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.0.3",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.3",
        "@vue/babel-plugin-jsx": "^1.1.1",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.22",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "form-backend-validation": "^2.3.3",
        "husky": "^8.0.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.41",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "postcss": "^8.3.11",
        "vue-loader": "^16.8.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.0",
        "inflector-js": "^1.0.1",
        "vue": "^3.2.37",
        "vuex": "^4.0.2"
    }
}
```

- Then I run `npm run dev` to build `.js` file to `public` folder, build process succeeded, but component doesn't show up, and Vue displays a warning
  [image]

I tried to override by using laravel nova custom field and change component field in `.php` file to `belongs-to-field`. Vue file context is copied same with origin file in vendor (`BelongsToField.vue`). After building component, it worked!

Thus, I think my problem not come from component file, it could be from Vue version or webpack config but I'm just new to Vue and cannot debug this error. Can someone help.

For more information: I've used this approach in laravel nova 3, and it worked.